# Audio/Video Streaming app iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

Is is possible to use Cordova/PhoneGap to grab audio and video from a mobile device and stream in to a web server in real time, and record this steam on the server, and also broadcast this stream to other app users with minimal delay?

What plugins/server-side applications are necessary to achieve this?